# Link to google maps in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-maps

So I'm wondering if people at Apple allows using links to Google maps in app. Or do they wan't u to use Apple maps? I have link to google mpas like that:

```
NSString *maps=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:maps]];
```

Can they make any problems about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maps URL format  [of Apple documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html). It looks like you can replace `maps.google.com` with `maps.apple.com.`

**Important:** In iOS 5.1 and earlier, the Map Kit framework uses the Google Mobile Maps (GMM) service to provide map data.

It turns out that the same is true in MobileSafari on `iOS 6;` tapping a link to `http://maps.apple.com?q=...` opens the Maps app with that search, the same way `http://maps.google.com?q=...` did on previous versions. I got curious and tried it and it worked, and then noticed that it's explicitly confirmed in the page linked above.

Comment: So if I get u right, instead of using maps.google.com i use maps.apple.com and result is basicly the same but guys on Apple will like me better :D